# wordpress "The provided host name is not valid for this server."

Tags: wordpress

Moving an Wordpress SSL site to a dev server. Deleted the certificate. Change the domain name through mysql. Getting this error.

What else would I need to do to fix this? Something on my end through apache? Done this countless times with other non-ssl sites...I am missing something I know it...
Thanks guys. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common Drupal error -- see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean .

I suspect that your web server is redirecting the request to a directory where a Drupal site is installed. Check your DNS A records and Apache configuration files (at /etc/apache2/sites-available on Ubuntu 18.04). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Checklist While moving a WordPress installation from one server to another (different URL)

- Update `siteurl` and `home` field in Database Table '`wp_options`' with http version of the url.
- Check `.htaccess` file and remove ssl redirect.
- Check if any plugin is used to replace non-https url with https url. Then disable this plugin.

Comment: I had tried all that. Even deleted the SSL docs. Still unresolved...I appreciate it.

Comment: From you description, I guess it is your website configuration issue. I would suggest, you can hire one professional to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this exact issue with a WordPress site and want to add a third solution on top of what @**tgeller** and @**Bikram Pahi** said.

Check that you have a self-signed certificate installed on your webserver or a purchased certificate. I solved this issue by installing a self-signed certificate and when re-opening the WordPress website, the error was no longer present.

Also, in my case, I enabled HTTPS in the site's URL settings.